# Simulate a network disconnect during testing

Tags: linux, iptables

I am user bob and I launch process `script.sh`. I'd like to block outbound requests made by script.sh to IP X.X.X.X.

bob is not root. bot is unable to get root.

I've tried with iptables using

```
iptables -A INPUT -s X.X.X.X -j DROP && service iptables save
```

But I get:

```
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
```

More context:

I'm working on a development env with multiple databases and systems. I'm writing some tests to try and simulate when connection between one of the systems is severed (and then reconnected). I'd prefer not to have to have my test run as root if they don't have to...

Comment: What do you want? An answer that's telling you how to circumvent your system's security?

Comment: iptables is built very intentionally not to allow configuration by unprivileged users, and for very good reasons. If you wanted a weaker approach -- ie. shadowing the relevant C library calls with an `LD_PRELOAD`able library -- that's doable, but also circumventable.

Comment: And how's this a programming question? Looks like basic Linux admin to me...

Comment: Kind of an odd setup as a general problem ("I don't want this one particular program to be able to connect to this one particular IP"). There might be a better solution if you elaborated on what you're doing -- maybe trying to run some code in a sandbox?

Comment: Hmm. You *could* run your program in something like a user-mode linux container, a qemu virtual machine, &c., and enable iptables rules at the root level inside said "guest".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So if the user has the ability to start the process executing the network request, I'm not sure if it is really "circumventing" the security. I'm not talking about blocking network requests on processes started by other users/administrators

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I'll add more context to the original question, stand by

Comment: @K2xL, it's the security that prevents iptables from being reconfigured by unprivileged users I'm speaking to being circumvented.

Comment: Tables are global -- there is no user-specific table you can configure for only your own processes.

Comment: Ahh -- so you want to simulate a disconnect on an open socket owned by a process you control? No reason to use iptables at all for that. I'd suggest editing your question to remove the misleading assumptions and focus on your real goal. That question might then be something like "simulating a network disconnect during testing".

Comment: Good idea @CharlesDuffy i updated the question

Comment: Can you talk a bit more about the details? Which language is the software under test written in? Is it a 3rd-party library actually making the network connection? Which one? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest setting up a very limited privilege escalation mechanism to allow `tcpkill` to be invoked by the user running your tests.

For instance in `/etc/sudoers`, you might have something like the following:

```
# allow tcpkill to be run under sudo by scripts
Defaults!/usr/sbin/tcpkill !requiretty

# allow testuser to invoke /usr/sbin/tcpkill for IP address 1.2.3.4
testuser: ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/tcpkill host 1.2.3.4
```